# jQuery code works differently on different servers

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery snippet:

```
$('#something').hover(
                function () {
                  $(this).stop().animate({'width':'220px'},1000, 'easeOutExpo').css('overflow','hidden'); 
                  $('.faded').stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
                },
                function () {
                  $(this).stop().animate({'width':'40px'},1000, 'easeOutExpo').css('overflow','visible'); 
                  $('.faded').stop().fadeTo('slow', 0);
                }
           );
```

for the following HTML:

```
< li id="something">< a href="someurl" title="a thing">< span class="faded">some text< /span>< /a>< /li>
```

this works like charm on my local server and my online server, but on the client server this snippet of code gets ignored totally and only the css :hover works instead even though other function in the same .js file works normally like it should.
so anyone can help why is it going this way?

Comment: Is it running the same version of jQuery?

Comment: yeah both running 1.8, it's on both servers i am not loading it from Google or other services

Comment: Are you using `$(document).ready()` to make sure that `#something` exists at the point where you try to access it?

Comment: Why did you revert the edit? It reads easier without the scrollbars.

Comment: it is from an external file.. also other functions before and after this one works correctly and they're all stored in the same external .js file.. only this one... another thing, when i put an alert or some border css-modification it works fine means it is getting loaded correctly

Comment: Also it may be important to note that this jQuery does not run on the server, unless you are somehow generating the javascript code then the server has no influence on its behavior. Does the code stop working when hosted on a different server or are you referring to Browsers as server?

Comment: So as mdsl said, _are_ you using `$(document).ready()`? Or is the external script included at the end of the body (after the element in question)?

Comment: @cernunnos no it's static code, i am not using any server-side techniques with this.. but both servers having the same php version i checked on that even though it has nothing to do with a the .js file. and servers as servers not as browsers

Comment: @nnnnnn, No it's on the head section and not in a $(document).ready() but if it is not loaded why would all other parts of codes contaiend in that external file, even the ones that initiates the default states, everything works except this, also if this is the problem wouldn't it be the same on the both online servers?

Comment: Yes, I'd expect it to be a problem on both servers. However, if the script is included in the head you need to use either a ready or an onload handler to attach event handlers, so really the weird part is that it works anywhere. Try adding a ready handler into the JS file, just around the code shown in the question (not around the whole file).

Comment: I moved the external .js file include to after </body> but nothing changed at all.. As i mentioned earlier I have already tried popping up an alert and it worked, changes some border-color changing on hover and it works too.

Comment: Check the javascript that is being sent by the server, check the HTML to see if the <li id="something"> exists, and always wrap event handlers in a .ready(). The server or php version have nothing to do with static javascript. Make sure you are not getting a cached version of the javascript/html. Really, the information on the question is not enough for us to help you and you seem to be under the impression that the server is somehow executing the static javascript file.

Comment: @cernunnos, the JavaScript is working fine concerning everything else other than this code and the <li> element does exist and I already said that when i do something like `$(this).css('border', '3px solid red')` or when i alert it works when it should, and yes you're right i know that the server or php version has nothing to do with it it's all the browser job to execute it. i moved it to after the `</body>` and included it in a `.ready()` but nothing changed at all. still working on the local and one of the online servers and not working on the other server. and it's not cached.. thanks

Comment: You've said you have the same jQuery version on both servers - do they both have the easing plugin present though? If it's working for other actions I can only assume that it's having some issue with jQuery stuff - does your browser console not have any output? Ctrl+Shift+J in chrome / Firebg

Comment: yes both, both JavaScript files and functions are identical and also I've removed the `easeOutExpo` option and that didn't make any difference, also I'm using the same easing property on another part of the page and it works normally.. it seems so confusing I know I just can't figure out why